# .htaccess Rewrite rule for clean URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to have a formatted URL like this:

```
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=1
```

where:

```
"id" range: 1-99 (without leading "0" from 1 to 9)
"id": always lowercase, no "Id" or "ID" or "iD"
```

Anything different from this format must redirect it to
**www.example.com/view.php**

Examples of **bad** URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/view.php?iD=1
https://www.example.com/view.php?Id=1
https://www.example.com/view.php?ID=1
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=1aaa
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=av1102
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=07
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=100
```

So far I have this:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view.php$
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(id=[1-9][0-9]{0,1})$).*$
   RewriteRule .* /view.php? [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work, either doesn't redirect or I receive well known "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" loop.

Please, help.

Comment: You rule redirects `view.php` to itself that's why you are getting an infinite loop error/Too many redirects . What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: If query string is not formatted like is written above the page must be redirected to view.php. For example https://www.example.com/view.php?id=1dsdaf, or https://www.example.com/view.php?iD=10 or https://www.example.com/view.php?id=99999 all goes to https://www.example.com/view.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=([1-9]{1,2}|[1-9a-zA-Z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /view.php? [L,R]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser or clear your  browser cache before testing this.

Comment: %{QUERY_STRING} and not ℅{QUERYSTRING}, even corrected it doesn't work, loads another view.php page on top of another view.php